# I don't understand why test.each() is skipping tests

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to use jest's [test.each()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout) function. Here is my code:

```
describe('Parser', () => {
...
  test.each( tests )('%s',
                     (testname, fname) => {
                       var content = fs.readFileSync( path.join( __dirname, fname ) )
                       const document = parse(tokenize(content))
                       expect(document).toMatchSnapshot()
                     }
                    );
})
```

But when I run in jest all these tests are skipped.

```
 FAIL  packages/orga/src/parse/__tests__/parser.spec.ts   Parser
    ✕ works (27 ms)
    ○ skipped can handle blocks
    ○ skipped can handle broken blocks 1
    ○ skipped can handle broken blocks 2
    ○ skipped can handle drawers
    ○ skipped can handle broken drawers
    ○ skipped can handle timestamp after headline
    ○ skipped can handle nested headlines
    ○ skipped can handle unordered list
    ○ skipped can handle ordered list
    ○ skipped can handle nested list
    ○ skipped can handle multi line list item
    ○ skipped can handle broken multi line list item 1
    ○ skipped can handle broken multi line list item 2
    ○ skipped can handle descriptive list 1
    ○ skipped can handle descriptive list 2
    ○ skipped can handle table
    ○ skipped can handle table with inline style
    ○ skipped can handle html export
    ○ skipped can handle html export block
    ○ skipped can handle affiliated keywords
    ○ skipped can handle invalid affiliated keywords 1
    ○ skipped can handle invalid affiliated keywords 2
    ○ skipped can handle paragraph
    ○ skipped can handle footnote
    ○ skipped can handle multi line footnote
    ○ skipped can handle complex footnote
    ○ skipped knows when headline can stop footnote
    ○ skipped knows when footnote can stop footnote
    ○ skipped knows when empty lines can stop footnote
    ○ skipped can handle TODO keywords
    ○ skipped can handle multiple TODO keywords
```

I understand that if the created test isn't given a function to parse that tests are reported as skipped, but I think I got it right here.  Don't I?  Could the fact that this is written in typescript have anything to do with this?

Comment: Never mind.  I ignored that some other test was using [test.only()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testonlyname-fn-timeout) which means skip everything else.

Comment: Congratulations, you just experienced the [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) technique :-)